# NextJS App Router - Move away from useState and move the state to the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have some data in my config file that I map through and return in my page.tsx
By default the page shows all images. I have 4 buttons to filter through the images. I take the category fro my data config and match it with the button value. When I click a button e.g. Animals then it only shows images from the animal category and so on.

I achieve this the following way in my `page.tsx` (minimal working example here on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/BearCooder/AppRouter/main?workspaceId=f4b731be-a853-47e0-bbd3-c6f7c81934e4))

```
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import artworks from "../Gallery";
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Gallery({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  const selectedImage = Number(searchParams.id);
  const page = searchParams["page"] ?? "1";
  const per_page = searchParams["per_page"] ?? "10";

  const start = (Number(page) - 1) * Number(per_page);
  const end = start + Number(per_page);
  const current = Number(page);

  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const entries = artworks.slice(start, end);

  const filterByCategory = (category: string | null) => {
    setSelectedCategory(category);
  };

  const isCategorySelected = (category: string) =>
    selectedCategory === category;

  const filteredEntries = selectedCategory
    ? entries.filter((artwork) => artwork.category === selectedCategory)
    : entries;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col row-2 gap-2 items-center">
      <div className="flex justify-center mb-4">
        <button
          onClick={() => filterByCategory(null)}
          className={`mr-2 ${
            isCategorySelected("") ? "bg-blue-500 text-white" : ""
          }`}
        >
          All
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => filterByCategory("Nature")}
          className={`mr-2 ${
            isCategorySelected("Nature") ? "bg-green-500 text-white" : ""
          }`}
        >
          Nature
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => filterByCategory("Animal")}
          className={`mr-2 ${
            isCategorySelected("Animal") ? "bg-red-500 text-white" : ""
          }`}
        >
          Animal
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => filterByCategory("Architecture")}
          className={`mr-2 ${
            isCategorySelected("Architecture") ? "bg-purple-500 text-white" : ""
          }`}
        >
          Architecture
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
        {filteredEntries.map((artwork) => (
          <Fragment key={artwork.id}>
            <div className="p-10 m-10">
              <Link href={`/${artwork.id}`}>
                <figure className="w-[300px] pb-2 bg-gray rounded-lg drop-shadow-xl group">
                  <h1 className="text-xl font-bold bg-golden-gradient text-transparent bg-clip-text">
                    {artwork.title}
                  </h1>
                  <Image
                    src={artwork.coverImage}
                    title={`Artwork ${artwork.title}`}
                    alt=""
                    placeholder="blur"
                  />
                </figure>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see I use `useState`. I am now in the process to rewrite the component so it saves the state in the URL. This means when I click the button animal I have the same behaviour but the URL changes with the query to something like this `localhost:3000/gallery?filter=${category}`

**I was thinking to use useRouter from next navigation and then push the route with the button click e.g.**

```
`router.push(`/gallery?filter=${category}`);`
```

But however I still would use `const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState<string | null>(null);` in this case and thus I would still mark the page as client component.
I am not sure at this point how to substitue the useState for the filter so I have the state in the URL and a Server component?

**EDIT:**
Ok I managed to create filter button that changes the url, but unfortunately I get a 404 error instead of showing only the category. This is my progress:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { createUrl } from "./utils";

interface FilterButtonsProps {
  categories: string[];
}

export default function FilterButtons({ categories }: FilterButtonsProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const newParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());

  const handleFilter = useCallback(
    (category: string) => {
      const currentCategory = newParams.get("category");
      if (currentCategory === category) {
        // Deselect the category
        newParams.delete("category");
      } else {
        // Select the category
        newParams.set("category", category);
      }

      router.push(createUrl("/filter", newParams));
    },
    [router, newParams]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <button
          key={category}
          onClick={() => handleFilter(category)}
          className={`mr-2 ${
            searchParams.get("category") === category
              ? "bg-blue-500 text-white"
              : "bg-gray-300"
          }`}
        >
          {category}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```